Is there a pairing technique for round robin fairness among duplicate values in a pairing heap?
I am implementing a priority queue using a pairing heap. I have a working implementation that supports the following operations.

Push O(1).
Pop O(lgN).
Erase O(lgN).
Decrease Key o(lgN).

My priority queue elements are defined as follows:
struct pq_elem
{
    struct pq_elem *left_child;
    struct pq_elem *next_sibling;
    struct pq_elem *prev_sibling;
    struct pq_elem *parent;
};

The structure of the tree is the ring representation suggested by Fredman et al. in their origninal paper on the data structure on page 125, figure 14. I have added in the doubly linked list to support a fast erase and decrease key operation.
Is there a merge and pair technique to ensure elements with duplicate values in the priority queue are popped in First In First Out order? Pseudo code is fine.
If you understand the question, you can stop reading here. If you would like an example of how my priority queue currently pushes and pops elements, and why it does not exhibit round robin fairness among duplicate values, keep reading.
I will push the following elements in the following order (left to right) into the priority queue. The vl is the key and the id is used to illustrate the order elements are pushed and popped.
|id 0| |id 1| |id 2| |id 3| |id 4| |id 5|
|vl 1| |vl 9| |vl 1| |vl 9| |vl 1| |vl 9|

Ideally, here is the order I would get when popping the elements from the priority queue (left to right).
|id 0| |id 2| |id 4| |id 1| |id 3| |id 5|
|vl 1| |vl 1| |vl 1| |vl 9| |vl 9| |vl 9|

In practice, my priority queue does not pop in this order, and here is a full sequence of tree merge and delete min operations that illustrates why. My delete min operation is a one-pass right to left pairing and accumulation operation.
push val = 1

|id:0|
|vl:1|

push val = 9

    |id:0|
    |vl:1|
   /
|id:1|
|vl:9|

push val = 1

     |id:0|
     |vl:1|
    /
|id:2||id:1|
|vl:1||vl:9|

push val = 9

     |id:0|
     |vl:1|
    /
|id:3||id:2||id:1|
|vl:9||vl:1||vl:9|

push val = 1

     |id:0|
     |vl:1|
    /
|id:4||id:3||id:2||id:1|
|vl:1||vl:9||vl:1||vl:9|

push val 9

     |id:0|
     |vl:1|
    /
|id:5||id:4||id:3||id:2||id:1|
|vl:9||vl:1||vl:9||vl:1||vl:9|

pop id = 0

|id:5||id:4|     |id:2||id:1|
|vl:9||vl:1|     |vl:1||vl:9|
                /
            |id:3|
            |vl:9|

         |
         v

|id:5||id:4|     |id:2|
|vl:9||vl:1|     |vl:1|
                /
            |id:1||id:3|
            |vl:9||vl:9|

         |
         v

     |id:4|       |id:2|
     |vl:1|       |vl:1|
    /            /
|id:5|       |id:1||id:3|
|vl:9|       |vl:9||vl:9|

         |
         v

          |id:2|
          |vl:1|
         /
     |id:4||id:1||id:3|
     |vl:1||vl:9||vl:9|
    /
|id:5|
|vl:9|

pop id = 2

     |id:4|      |id:3|
     |vl:1|      |vl:9|
    /
|id:1||id:5|
|vl:9||vl:9|

     |
     v

     |id:4|
     |vl:1|      
    /
|id:3||id:1||id:5|
|vl:9||vl:9||vl:9|

pop id = 4

      |id:1||id:5|
      |vl:9||vl:9|
     /
|id:3|
|vl:9|

     |
     v
           |id:5|
           |vl:9|
          /
      |id:1|
      |vl:9|
     /
|id:3|
|vl:9|

pop id = 5

      |id:1|
      |vl:9|
     /
|id:3|
|vl:9|

pop id = 1

|id:3|
|vl:9|

pop id = 3


The final pop sequence was:
|id 0| |id 2| |id 4| |id 5| |id 1| |id 3|
|vl 1| |vl 1| |vl 1| |vl 9| |vl 9| |vl 9|

The order of elements is preserved during the push phase because the newest value takes the left child position of the parent. But the pairing phase during a delete min operation modifies the order among elements with equivalent values. Any ideas on how to make the delete min operation preserve FIFO order for elements with duplicate values would be appreciated. I can also provide the current code for delete_min and merge if requested but the post is already quite long.

Add a millisecond timestamp to each element to find out the exact priority?

@user24714692 This could be possible. However, this is a "heap free" generic data structure written in C. So the struct pq_elem is embedded in a user defined struct and they manage their own memory. The user also defines a callback function for comparison that returns a three way comparison value and a pointer to that function is stored with the priority queue. So comparisons are pretty much a black box from my perspective. It could be possible to add timestamp comparison on top of that but might be tricky as this implementation is meant for lower level OS kernel development.

Without additional information to differentiate the equal keys (such as the millisecond timestamp suggested in the earlier comment), there is no way to guarantee removal order and still maintain the O(1) insertion and O(log n) removal. Your own demonstration of how the order changes should be sufficient proof of that. Seems like you could add that timestamp to your pq_elem structure and have it automatically populated when an item is inserted. If the client's comparison returns equal, then you compare the timestamps to determine which one is smaller.

Good points. Perhaps pushing the tie break time stamping onto the user’s struct/comparison function would not be horrible if it was documented well and the user needs that behavior. No need to specialize the data structure in that way. Also, proving it is not possible to achieve round robin with merges and pairs could be the accepted answer. Maybe proving it myself more formally would be a good exercise when I have time.
